# pagination Active class

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I trying to active class on list

class="active"

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $perpage); 
echo '<ul class="pagination">'; 
echo "<li><a href='topics.php?page=1'>".'<'."</a></li> ";  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
echo "<li  ><a href='topics.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> "; 
}; 
echo "<li><a href='topics.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>'."</a> </li>"; 

echo '</ul> ';
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't. Instead have a separate table that links meetings and attendants. Insert a row in that table for each attendant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only store ids(ID of user table) of the selected users in meeting table Attendants field in comma(,) separated.
Let say users with id 1,7 and 5 are selected then store 1,5,7 to meeting table
At the time of fetching you can fetch users as

```
$q="SELECT username from user_table where ID IN (1,5,7)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

for example

```
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```